# Why is audio missing from this MP4 when played through headphones on an IPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, video-streaming, html5-audio, mp4

I have a web application and am doing some testing for IPads.

If I open this link (https://itype.techforge.com.au/assets/videos/repeated/WordRat.mp4) in Safari it plays fine, with audio, when no headphones are plugged in.

If I plug in headphones the audio disappears.

However if I open this link (https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4) the audio works both with and without headphones plugged in.

What is different about the 2 videos that is causing this?  Is it possible that headers are the reason for this?  What do I need to do so that my video will also have sound when headphones are plugged in?

Thanks!

Edit: I've ruled out headers by serving both mp4s from my server (https://itype.techforge.com.au/assets/videos/sample-mp4-file.mp4).  The sample version still works, so the problem is something in the mp4s themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The left and right channels are out of phase. When you plug in the headphones, the channels are mixed to mono, they cancel each other out.

https://www.uaudio.com/blog/understanding-audio-phase/

Comment: That sounds plausible, although why would the signal be changed to mono when headphones are plugged in?

Comment: I'm not sure if this checks out.  I just tried setting all audio on the IPad to mono (https://www.imore.com/how-enable-mono-audio-auditory-accessibility-iphone-or-ipad) and the audio still plays fine when head phones are not plugged in.

Edit: Actually just tested some more, adjusted the balance for the mono audio to only the right channel and now the sound is back.  This seems to confirm your theory.  Now I need to work out why Adobe Animate + Media Encoder output is like this.  I wonder if it could be the original wav file...

Comment: Although, when I set windows to play all audio as mono I still get sound.